# Transformation of graphs of the functions.

Tags: graphing-functions

How to graph functions like $y=x+\sin x$ or functions having addition or subtraction of different variables?

Comment: Most people would use a computer... such functions are not that easy to draw by hand.

Comment: Remark : In this case you can just take the graph of $y = \sin x$ and slant it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a rough sketch, consider the derivative: $y'=1+\cos x$. Unlike the derivative of sine wave (which alternates between $\pm $), this one is never negative, but it periodically drops to zero. This means the shape resembles a smooth staircase: quickly up, then level out, repeat.

[image: graph]